# Serializing differently depending on the data in django rest frame work

Tags: django-rest-framework

I am having some troubles serializing the object differently, depending its data.

I want to return the post data to the client, which includes information like 'title', 'contents', 'author', 'is_anonymous'.

Here's the problem. 
When I got a request requiring data, the 'is_anonymous' field of which is 'true', I shouldn't give 'author' field.

I tried to customize the 'list' or 'receive' method in ViewSet, but even though I  classified the 'anonymous' one and ones that are not, it still goes through the same serializer. So, I concluded that it's about the serializers, not viewset.

What should I do for this?

Comment: As far as I know, DRF is not really set up to serve lists of resources with different structures (i.e., excluding a field for some objects but not others).  Would it suffice to change the anonymous `author` fields to `null` or something hardcoded like `"Anonymous"`?

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at overriding the `to_representation()` method of your serializer. Here's a simple example of what I mean.

```
class ExampleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        rep = super().to_representation(instance)
        if instance.is_anonymous:
            rep["author"] = None
            # del rep["author"]
        return rep
```

Here I am calling the regular `to_representation()` method, and then modifying the results based on the `is_anonymous` property.  [You may want to familiarise yourself with the implementation of `to_representation(instance)`](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/serializers.py#L506-L530)